# NiceTabular (NiceMatrix) Empty Line without Vertical Rules

Tags: tables, nicematrix

I am trying to add a small, empty line in a `NiceTabular` environment. The `NiceMatrix` [manual](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/nicematrix/nicematrix.pdf) states (Section 5.1.1 The vertical rules):

> In the environments of nicematrix, the vertical rules specified by | in the preambles of the environments
> are never broken, even by an incomplete row or by a double horizontal rule specified by \hline\hline

Which means that the empty line here shows the vertical rules:

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \small
    \centering
    \begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}{ll}[hvlines]
        \textit{Year}
        &
        \textit{Fruit}
    \\ \hline \hline
        2022
        &
        Apple
    \\
    \end{NiceTabularX}
\end{table}
```

[image]

A quick attempt at a block gave a full-height line that still included the outermost (=border) vertical rules.

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \small
    \centering
    \begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}{ll}[hvlines]
        \textit{Year}
        &
        \textit{Fruit}
    \\ \Block{1-2}{\hline \hline} \\
        2022
        &
        Apple
    \\
    \end{NiceTabularX}
\end{table}
```

[image]

How can I get a small empty line between rows without any vertical rules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the rules of the classical `{tabular}` (of the package `array` which is loaded by `nicematrix`).

That means that:

- you use the classical command `\hline` (and `\hline\hline` for the double rule);
- you have to define a column type with the behavior of the classical `|` of `array` (that classical `|` of `array` has been overwritten by `nicematrix`): `\newcolumntype{I}{!{\vrule}}` will do the job.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{I}{!{\vrule}}

\begin{table}[h]
\small
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{IlIlI}
    \hline
    \textit{Year}
    &
    \textit{Fruit} \\
    \hline\hline
    2022
    &
    Apple \\
    \hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Of course, in that example, there is no point using `{NiceTabular}` (I would use `{tabular}`) but you probably want to use other features provided by `nicematrix` in your real tabular).

[image: Output of the above code]

---

On the other hand, remember that the main feature of `nicematrix` is to insert PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells, columns and rows of a classical `{tabular}`. That means that it's always possible to draw whatever rule you want with Tikz by using those nodes.

```
\begin{table}[h]
\small
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ll}[hvlines]
    \textit{Year}
    &
    \textit{Fruit} \\
    2022
    &
    Apple \\
\CodeAfter
    \tikz \draw [line width = 2 \pgflinewidth] (2-|1) -- (2-|last) ; 
    \tikz \draw [white, shorten > = -1 pt, shorten <= -1 pt] (2-|1) -- (2-|last) ; 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]